# C# SCCM Application: Application Deployment Type Requirements: [One of] Operating Systems

Tags: c#, deployment, types, sccm

I am developing a utility/shell-extension application for my organisation that will allow colleagues to create SCCM applications and packages by right-clicking on a source file (.MSI, .MST, .EXE &c.) in Windows Explorer.

I am not able to set the

> Setting Operating System requirements (e.g. "One of... &c.")

in an Application's Deployment Type.

I have been using an extremely useful [sample C# application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sample-SCCM-Application-376c9124/sourcecode?fileId=82119&pathId=548392900) for "inspiration", which does include a method of adding a `Global Condition` as a requirement to a `Deployment Type`... But I haven't been able to transpose the elements of that code into something that will add an OS Requirement to a DT.

I found some `Powershell` scripts that look like they would do the job but I haven't been able to successfully transpose the PS examples `into C#`.

The specific issue I am having is that I have no idea how to construct the (rather complex-looking) `DesiredConfigurationManagement` expression(s).

There are `ExpressionBase`, `GlobalSettingReference`,  `Expression` and `Rule` objects that I cannot figure out what to do with... And the SCCM 2012 SDK documentation and samples has not helped me to clarify the `DesiredConfigurationManagement` at all.

**So my questions then:**

1) I assume I must use `DesiredConfigurationManagement` to set OS Requirements for a Deployment Type. Is this correct? Or is there an easier way to add the OS Requirement using WMI queries &c?

2) Does anybody know of any Web resources that can/might guide me through the mysteries of DCM Expression building, with a particular focus on C# syntax?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Hi, I tend to upvote this question since you put a lot of effort in it. But I think, in it's current form it is unlikely you'll receive a lot of attention. There are a couple of things which should be altered, for reference see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask **1)** information about requirements is irrelevant; keep it short and simple. **2)** pinpoint the exact problem **3)** provide an example (minimal) of what you have tried and what the result was.... I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the helpful feedback. Like I said: "First Time Caller"..! (Or I would have known not to hit "Enter" after that first line..!") (OK. No carriage returns in comments..!) I guess I got stuck with the _"Introduce the problem before you post any code"_ bit. It isn't exactly a code problem... More one of General Ignorance! The exact problem being that I don't know how to add an OS Requirement to an SCCM Application Deployment Type in a C# application. And I didn't want to clutter the post with examples of my failed attempts. But like I said: thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the edit of my original question Stefan. Can see what you mean now! :)

Answer (score 0):

So maybe it was the act of composing my thoughts for my question here... But I finally managed to transpose the code from Powershell!

```
        CustomCollection<RuleExpression> oOperands = new CustomCollection<RuleExpression>();

        oOperands.Add(new RuleExpression("Windows/All_x64_Windows_7_Client"));

        ExpressionOperator oOperator = ExpressionOperator.OneOf;

        OperatingSystemExpression oOSExpression = new OperatingSystemExpression(oOperator, oOperands);

        Annotation oAnnotation = new Annotation();

        oAnnotation.DisplayName = new LocalizableString("DisplayName", "Operating system One of (All Windows 7 (64-bit))", null);

        NoncomplianceSeverity oNonComplianceSeverity = NoncomplianceSeverity.None;

        Rule nextRule = new Rule("Rule_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B").Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty), oNonComplianceSeverity, oAnnotation, oOSExpression);

        thisDT.Requirements.Add(nextRule);
```

Seems to do the job!